# Can i still locate my samsung phone if it is reformatted?

Tags: security

I lost my samsung phone but i registered it to samsung account? Can i still locate it if the person who got it already reformatted the phone?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **no**. As soon as your phone is formatted or factory reset, no information is left from previous use, and so the Samsung account is not connected to the phone anymore, making it impossible for Samsung to locate your phone.